# No puedo resolver @Transactional

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, maven, jwt

ocupo Spring boot en la version 3.1.3, y el @Transactional no se inicia y no puedo seguir con mi proyecto con maven

intenten agregar la dependencia con maven pero no me aparecio en la busqueda